# C# WebUtility.HtmlEncode at .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, html-encode

I'm making an (form) application, with the possibility to send a notification mail.

On my application there are two variables, that will be placed into the html body of the mail. One of them is a number, but the second is a name, which can contain the < and > characters.

I found an useful function to encode this, but the `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String);` only works on .NET 4.0, while my app is programmed in .NET 3.0.

Is there a simple function to replace the `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String);` which works in .NET 3.0?

Comment: The application i need it for, is made in .NET Framework 3.0.

Comment: Fair enough, worth checking though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode exists from 1.1

Comment: For some reason, my platform doesn't see more then System.Web.
Forgive me for being a newb. (A)

Comment: @Ivar - Add the System.Web.dll assembly as a reference to your project

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(...);
```

In `System.Web.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx).